# Multivariable piecewise continuity + notation for "x ≠ y except when x = y = 1/2"

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, piecewise-continuity

In the problem, I have to find the subset of the domain Z = {(x, y) $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^2$ | x, y > 0} for which the following function is continuous:

\begin{equation*}
h(x,y) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            f(x,y) & \text{if x $\neq$ y} \\
            g(x,y) & \text{if $x=y$}
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

I have proved that the $\lim_{(x,y) \to (n,n)} f(x,y)$ = g(n,n) when n =$\frac12$

I took this to mean that h(x,y) is continuous for {x>0, y>0, x $\neq$ y except when x=y=$\frac12$}

Could I write this as D = [f(x, y) $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^2$ | x>0, y>0, x $\neq$ y \ {x=y=$\frac12$}]?

I might have completely missed the mark, but any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as
$$\{(x, y) \in (0, \infty) \times (0, \infty) \mid x \neq y\} \cup \left\{\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)\right\}.$$
Just as a word of caution, you shouldn't use the set difference when dealing with equations. Writing $x \neq y \setminus \{x = y = \frac{1}{2}\}$ doesn't make sense. I understand what you're going for (you're reading \ as "except for"), but this is not how the notation works. It's really only used for sets.